Access database kicks user out after entry to a text box in a datasheet section of a split form
I have a split database, using MS Access 2016 with multiple frontends and a backend on a shared drive with links to the tables in the backend.
Database crashes, kicks users out when users update a textbox "txtPMT", and pushes  in the datasheet section of the split form. These crashes usually wipe out the previous records the users were working on.
I would like user to be able to update txtPMT and hit  without being kicked out of the database.
I have tried Me.Requery in the "On Change" event of the textbox, but the problem persists. I have also reviewed the Split Form Datasheet section of its Property Sheet and it "Allows Edits". I am lost, Please help.
Thanks for any insight anybody can provide.

As the first step, check client settings of the backend whether it is opened in shared or exclusive mode, and also the record locking settings.

The Default Open mode is "shared", and Default record locking is set to "No Locks".

"No lock" means Access should warn If a record is edited concurrently and asks for user action but the program should not crash. If every user has their own copy of frontend, and also all users have full read/write permission to the backend folder, then it might be the from settings/code. Please try to edit/insert table data directly in a frontend and check if it works.
